# Method to bound/constrain a matrix elementwise in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent

In TensorFlow, I currently have a matrix that represents the weights between layers of a Neural Network. However, I am trying to implement some kind of projected/constrained gradient descent, where the weights are bounded between some interval, and after each step that interval changes. I understand that TensorFlow has [tf.clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value), but my requirements are that the intervals for the weights aren't all the same. How can I implement something similar to clip_by_value but where I can vary the bounds for individual elements of the matrix?

Comment: You can pass another tensor for the clip values to `tf.clip_by_value` which performs element-wise clipping.

Comment: Ah that worked perfectly, thanks!